# Android AOSP Audio Issue

Tags: android, audio, android-source, android-audiomanager, automotive

I have cloned the source code of the android 13 [AOSP Automotive Build](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/reference/build-numbers#source-code-tags-and-builds) with build id TQ3C.230901.001.B1. The issue I am facing is if I build emulator for the lunch target : ***sdk_car_x86_64-userdebug*** it's working fine but the issue is audio is not working when i use media player.

```
2024-02-06 16:38:38.986  2111-2111  MediaPlayer             com...ia.localmediaplayer  E  Error (1,-2147483648)
2024-02-06 16:38:39.036   507-3924  NuPlayerDecoder         mediaserver                E  Failed to create audio/vorbis decoder
2024-02-06 16:38:39.036   507-3921  NuPlayer                mediaserver                E  received error(0x80000000) from audio decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down
2024-02-06 16:38:39.036  2111-3714  MediaPlayerNative       com...ia.localmediaplayer  E  error (1, -2147483648)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem but did not find a solution. In my case, I just needed to verify the audio output, so I opted to input raw audio data into AudioTrack.